# Loop through dataframe and change all columns that end in Date from character to date class with format %d-%m-%Y

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

I can a very large dataframe with over 200 columns and multiple different columns that end in "date". I am fairly new to loops and lists and haven't been able to get anything to work. I want to loop through the dataframe and check which columns end in "Date" and change its class to a class Date with the format %d-%m-%Y. I tried the following;

```
myData[apply(myData[, endsWith(colnames(myData), "Date")], 1, function(x) as.Date(x)), ]
```

I get the error : Error in charToDate(x) :
character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

any help is appreciated. I am using the dplyr and lubridate package

Comment: `apply` may not be a an option here as it can convert to matrix and this coerce the Date class to numeric storage value.  I addition, the `format = '%/d-%m-%Y'` in `as.Date`.  Based on the code, you the Date converted values are used as row index, and this can be a syntax issue as well.  without showing the data, it is difficult to know the exact problem.  Please use `dput` to show a small reproducible example

Comment: Yeah looks like your correct with apply. adding in the format argument changed the error from what it was previously to ; Error in `vectbl_as_row_location()`:
! Must subset rows with a valid subscript vector.
x Subscript `i` must be a simple vector, not a matrix.

Comment: `library(dplyr); myData %>% mutate(across(ends_with("Date"), ~lubridate::dmy(.)))`

Comment: Just to clarify, I assume you mean that you currently have text that is `%d-%m-%Y` and you want to change it to a Date class. The Date class will be by definition `%Y-%m-%d`.

Comment: @JonSpring That is correct.

Comment: I have tried ```mutate(across(where(is.Date), ~format(.,"%d-%m-%Y")))``` which worked to change the format from %Y-%m-%d to my intended format but changed the column class to character. Why would that be?